# How to get date and time from rfc399 ruby

Tags: ruby

How to get date and time form the following timestamp or parse date:

```
2015-09-23T07:12:54.404Z
```

Need to display time in format 23-09-2015, 7:54Am. Also need to get timeZone.

Comment: Do you mean RFC 3339?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime.parse("2015-09-23T07:12:54.404Z")

DateTime.parse("2015-09-23T07:12:54.404Z").strftime("%d-%m-%Y,%H:%M:%S")
=> "23-09-2015,07:12:54"

DateTime.parse("2015-09-23T07:12:54.404Z").strftime("%d-%m-%Y,%H:%M:%S%P")
=> "23-09-2015,07:12:54am"
```

if you want to get timeZone, just need to add `%z` or `%Z`.